# Do 'from:' search using linqtotwitter

Tags: c#, linq-to-twitter

I am doing the following -

```
TwitterContext twitterCtx = new TwitterContext(auth);
string searchTerm = "\"from:stephenfry\"";
List<Status> searchResponse =

    (from search in twitterCtx.Search
     where search.Type == SearchType.Search &&
           search.Query == searchTerm &&
           search.Count == 10 &&
           search.SinceID == 0 
     select search.Statuses)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

This is working fine and bringing back 10 tweets from the `@stephenfry` account. However I am trying to get tweets from my own account, which has publicly accessible tweets (I made sure the `Protect my Tweets` checkbox is unchecked in settings/security).

So I then authenticated my application against my own account to get a valid `OauthToken` and `OauthTokenSecret` so that the `twitterCtx` is fully authorised to access **all** tweets from my account however when I change the searchTerm to -

```
"\"from:myTwitterAccount\""
```

**still** `searchResponse` comes back with a count of zero??

It seems to be rather hit or miss as well as I have found other accounts that look to be publicly accessible however when doing the above procedure they aslo return zero posts whereas some work perfectly fine. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Would love an explanation of the down vote and close request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Search API only goes back a couple weeks and isn't a comprehensive search engine. Rather, it only display's according to an undocumented Twitter relevance algorithm:

[Twitter Search API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search)

In this case, @stephenfry is a validated account, which implies that Twitter considers the tweets relevant. I'm sure validated account isn't the only criteria, but might shed light on reasoning of why some tweets appear and others don't.

BTW, I think the question is fine and that's why they need multiple votes, to protect against outliers, before truly closing.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else trying to figure this out do this instead:

```
var tweets = await
(
    from tweet in twitterCtx.Status
    where   tweet.Type == StatusType.User &&
            tweet.ScreenName == "TheAccountsOnScreenName"
    select tweet
)
.ToListAsync();
```